# c# 8 switch expression: No best type was found for the switch expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-8.0, switch-expression

I have added a code in my startup class (.net core 3.1) to return the type based on parameter and I get compile-time errors.

I have created a running example in [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAoEgOwjDigAcIBjOAAgGEB7MqNgGzgEEaNIsQDeJJhKYBLMvAQAzBswCSACQhkUvBExFMAvuMnYAzEzxMAQtDjrN23QaMTT53EwCyATztbE+ECsbX20kJjUNPx09Q2JJczMLbxDEXEDrKFtI0PCU6KdSOON3bHwAdmddSvjSgDZzABZPCBkAClKABgBtAF0mCAQAcygASmrJMUL46ckANwGmAGs4LyYAXiYAIjAvAAts/02AbhJxmfmdfftEdaWVpigAdykYel2z6cmZ78ltvYOEPhNusAHxMMhwR6eHwA/CtEZID4/P5XKK4YFrMEQqHJAG4eGIoo/GYAfVBTBguwQbCh2KYADk2DBlGAaLwqLI4CgAKIAD0YNBgUg48KRkn0JymxIkFyYvNuy1WTxebzFEi+0umKNhGLBmy4VEpMkGm0Jmq1O1R2nR5P1bENu2NTDg3EyprV0zJmK2KDgigArtwYEx6DZNh6JacicTSgBOVqbVQu7hsJgAdTYCG4KAAhJsRpKfrF4rFYkA==). if switch expression contains the string or other objects it runs fine.

working example 1:

```
var x = key switch
            {
                "myhandler1" => "something",
                "myhandler2" => "something else",
                _ => "default case"
            };
```

working example 2:

```
object obj =  s switch {
            "a" => new object(),
            "b" => new DateTime(),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
        };
```

***Error example:***

```
interface IHandler { }
public class BaseHandler { }
public class MyHandler1: BaseHandler, IHandler { }
public class MyHandler2: BaseHandler, IHandler { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var key = "myhandler1";

        var handler = key switch
        {
            "myhandler1" => new MyHandler1(),
            "myhandler2" => new MyHandler2(),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
        };

        var x = key switch
        {
            "myhandler1" => "something",
            "myhandler2" => "something else",
            _ => "default case"
        };

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

***original problem (needs fixing):***

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<Func<string, IHandler>>(sp => key =>
            {
                return key switch
                {
                    Constants.Brand => sp.GetService<Handler1>(),
                    Constants.Series => sp.GetService<Handler2>(),
                    _ => throw new NotImplementedException()

                };
}
```

found this link: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2728

Thanks to **Pavel** and **Marc**, below is the fix:

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<Func<string, IHandler>>(sp => key =>
            {
                return key switch
                {
                    Constants.Brand => (sp.GetService<Handler1>() as IHandler),
                    Constants.Series => (sp.GetService<Handler2>() as IHandler),
                    _ => throw new NotImplementedException()

                };
}
```

Comment: It would work if `Handler1` and `Handler2` had a common base type/interface.

Comment: Since `DateTime` can be downcast to `object`, that works, but I assume that `MyHandler2` doesn't inherit from `MyHandler1` or vice versa. If these two types have a common base type, you can use that instead of `var` to give the compiler enough knowledge. ie. `MyHandlerBase handler = key switch { ... };`.

Comment: do `MyHandler1` and `MyHandler2` share a common base type? perhaps use that instead of `var`

Comment: @MarcGravell yes they both have baseType and interface. in sharplab I used BaseHandler/Ihandler it fixes the problem but when I apply same changes in startup DI class it still gives error.

Comment: maybe `return (IHandler) key switch...` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell your example will try to convert string key to IHandler and will fail, I just tested and it gave compile errors. I have updated the question with answer. Thank you

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should explicitly declare a type of handler, instead of `var`

```cs
IHandler handler = key switch //or BaseHandler handler = key switch
{
    "myhandler1" => new MyHandler1(),
    "myhandler2" => new MyHandler2(),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
};
```

In your [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) sample both handlers implement `IHandler` interface and inherit `BaseHandler` class, compiler simply doesn't know which type to use, you should tell it him explicitly

```cs
interface IHandler { }
public class BaseHandler { }
public class MyHandler1 : BaseHandler, IHandler { }
public class MyHandler2 : BaseHandler, IHandler { }
```

The same is true for the dependency injection sample, you should explicitly declare a type (assuming that `Handler1` and `Handler2` implement `IHandler`)

```cs
return key switch
{
    Constants.Brand => sp.GetService<Handler1>(),
    Constants.Series => (IHandler) sp.GetService<Handler2>(),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
};
```

You can do it only for one constant, compiler is smart enough to do the rest of job for you

Comment: thanks it does fix it but it doesn't fix the errors in dependency injection, I have updated my question,

Comment: @KamranPervaiz Can you share the compete sample fro DI in your question?

Comment: @KamranPervaiz Have you tried to follow this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2728#issuecomment-522845949) and explicitly declare a `Func`?

Comment: not sure how can I make it explicit in startup class.

Answer (score 2):

You're dealing with a covariance issue. You've specified that the return type of the `Func` should be `IHandler`, but this type param is invariant. As such, you have to actually return `IHandler`, not just a class that implements it.

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient<Func<string, IHandler>>(sp => key =>
{
    return key switch
    {
        Constants.Brand => (IHandler)sp.GetService<Handler1>(),
        Constants.Series => (IHandler)sp.GetService<Handler2>(),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is fussy - it wants things unambiguous, and it isn't obvious what type `handler` should be here since `MyHandler1` and `MyHandler2` are different types; basically, pick some common base type or implemented interface from `MyHandler1` and `MyHandler2`, and use that instead of `var`. At worst case, `object` should suffice:

```cs
object handler = key switch
{
    "myhandler1" => new MyHandler1(),
    "myhandler2" => new MyHandler2(),
    _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
};
```

The compiler won't attempt to do this itself.

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question for DI. not sure why it is not working for Dependency Injection when sharplab is working for common base type

Answer (score 0):

As for 2023 (C# Version 11, .NET 7), you can use dynamic object. Example:

```
string itemType = "cloth";
dynamic? item = itemType switch 
{
    "cloth" => new Cloth(),
    "food"  => new Food(),
    _       => null
};
```